# Best up-to-date alternative to the Enterprise Rails book

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to work on a Rails app that is going to grow beyond just simple CRUD requirements. So I had a look through good data architecture practices, and [Enterprise Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515200) came up. While I understand it covers mostly non-specific to Rail design choices (so it's still most definitely useful), it would be very nice to also find something which is at least more up-do-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been told, McAnally's "Ruby in Practice" could very well fit your needs:

[http://www.amazon.com/Ruby-Practice-Jeremy-McAnally/dp/1933988479](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988479)

Hope that helps!